# ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error in my react application in production: 
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')`
With sourcemap enabled, it shows error in **react.production.min.js**

What's strange is, I'm getting this only on a particular route. All other routes are working fine (Even though I'm using `useRef`s in multiple files.).

Since the local build is working fine, I'm unable to reproduce the issue locally.

I tried the following things:

1. Reverting to previous working commit.
2. Reinstalling `node_modules` on prod machine
3. Switching from Yarn to NPM

I'm using express to host the static build files. Here's the code:

```
const helmet = require('helmet');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: 'DENY' }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), {
        maxAge: 86400000,
    });
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    console.log(`Frontend start on http://localhost:8080`);
});
```

Edit:
React Component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const ConfigForm = (props) => {
    const scrollTopRef = useRef(null);

    const scrollToTop = () => {
        if (scrollTopRef && scrollTopRef.current) {
            scrollTopRef.current.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });
        }
    };

    const onButtonClick = () => {
        scrollToTop();
    }

    return (
        <div className="client-configs" ref={scrollTopRef}>
            <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Scroll To Top</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ConfigForm;
```

Comment: How many refs are you using that broken route? Can you verify if the ref is being initialized correctly in that route?

Comment: This is a front end issue, please include the front end react code in question.

Comment: The if statement looks ok. You could try changing  scrolTopRef = useRef({}). Have you definately rebuilt it and cleared any cache before retesting? Does it work in development mode? Might be worth having a dev build using webpack or nextjs to test it.

Comment: @SteveTomlin Yes tried with useRef({}) too. Still no progress. The build works locally. But the prod fails.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems related to react 18 and having different instances or versions of react in your app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371254/vincent-lecrubier: can you please expand on this? I am facing this same issue and have react 18 installed. I would not even know how I could use different react versions for production and locally, I only have two different config-files. I have v18 for react and react-dom installed - or can other packages react is working with create this issue too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route failed because of one of the packages I was using in the react component. It's `package.json` mentioned `"react": ">=16"`.

A few days ago, react v18 was released. The prod machine updated this package in `node_modules`. The package didn't support this and hence failed.

Locally the `node_modules` is not updated frequently. That being the reason, it worked locally and failed in production.

Lesson learned:

- Mention package version as `~version` or `^version`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/8660449).

Answer (score -1):

```
const scrollTopRef = useRef(null);
```

This essentially means the value of `scrollTopRef` is `null`.
Then you are using `scrollTopRef.current` which means you are trying to access `current` attritube on null which is an error. Hence you need to set `scrollTopRef` to some meaningful value.

The useRef Hook allows you to persist values between renders.

It can be used to store a mutable value that does not cause a re-render when updated.

Comment: In the React component code, I've already mentioned ref={scrollTopRef} to div element. This fills ref with `{ current: {} }`. Also the code is working locally.

Answer (score -1):

The Simple solution for the error is to install the latest version of `react-router-dom` by writing `npm install react-router-dom`.

Comment: This worked for me - I had two sets of node modules within my react app (Not sure how I didn't notice lol) but I removed the extra node modules and reinstalled react-router-dom and it was all good. However I knew my problem was not the same as this question as I hadn't referenced useRef anywhere but still a useful comment nevertheless.